# same code, different servers, different output

Tags: php, apache

The code in question :

```
<?php /*tests added by jason*/
    echo "<br />";
    echo "count = " . $this->countModules('showcase'); 
    echo "<br />";
    echo "hidebyview = " . $hideByView;
    echo "<br />";
    if($hidebyview == true) {
        echo "T";
    }
    else {
        echo "F";
    }
    echo "<br />";
    if ($this->countModules('showcase') && $hideByView == false) {
        echo "pass";
    }
    else {
        echo "fail";
    }
    echo "<br />";
?>
```

Site 1 output Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7 (where everything works fine):

```
count = 1
hidebyview = 
F
pass
```

Site 2 output Apache/2.2.13 (Win32) PHP/5.3.26 (where the thing is broken) :

```
count = 1
hidebyview = 1
F
fail
```

I guess it boils down to how can the part that evaluates to "fail" evaluate to different answers?

Comment: Where is '$hideByView' set?

Comment: It does not appear to be set anywhere. That was one of my questions as well. Im currently going through the entire chain of includes (its a joomla site) grepping for where its set, what it is, etc. But, since the test site and the remote site have the same code, I thought maybe it wasnt intended to be set.

Comment: its being set in an included file. false is the correct setting.

Answer (score 0):

`$hideByView == false` is not (always) equal to `!($hidebyview == true)` because of casting and other possible automatic conversions. So your debug info is not really showing you what your expression `$hideByView == false` evaluates to.

Comment: only in php is the opposite of false not true lol. Thank you, I think this will help.